# The transversal pre-image of a manifold with boundary

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, transversality

I am reading "transversal pre-image of a manifold with boundary" from Differential Topology by M. Hirsch. I have some confusion regarding Theorem 4.2. on the [page 31](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Differential_Topology/emTmBwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=The+proofs+of+Theorems+4.1+and+4.2+are+left+to+the+reader.The+embedding+Theorems+3.4+and+3.5+go+through+with+only+minorchanges.+With+some+care+one+can+prove:&pg=PA31&printsec=frontcover).[image]

Notice that the first highlight says ''theorem for $\partial$-manifold'' but Theorem 4.2. doesn't mention whether $M$ is $\partial$-manifold or not (i.e.,  $\partial M$ is non-empty or empty). Though in theorem 4.1., it is explicitly mentioned $M$ is a $\partial$-manifold.

> *Question 1:* Does it mean that I can take $\partial M$ is non-empty as well as
> empty both in theorem 4.2.?

Let $M:=\big\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2:y\geq 0\big\}$, $N:=\partial M=\Bbb R\times 0$, $A=[0,1]\times 0$, and $f\colon M\to N$ be the projection map $M\ni (x,y)\longmapsto x\in N$. Certainly, $A\subset N\backslash \partial N$ and $\dim T_a A=1=\dim T_a N$ for each $a\in A$. That is $f\pitchfork A$ and $f\big|\partial M\pitchfork A$.   But, $\partial f^{-1}(A)=(0\times \Bbb R)\cup A\cup (1\times \Bbb R)\neq (0\times \Bbb R)\cup  (1\times \Bbb R)=f^{-1}(\partial A)$

> *Question 2:* Shouldn't it be $\partial f^{-1}(A)=\big(f^{-1}(A)\cap
>  \partial M\big)\cup f^{-1}(\partial A)$? Of course, if $\partial M=\varnothing$, then it is correct.

The following picture is taken from Differential Topology by Alan Pollack and Victor Guillemin which contains the special case, namely when $\partial A=\varnothing$. See page 60. [image]

Comment: Reread Theorem 4.2. Do you not see $f|\partial M$?

Comment: I think, you are saying about Question 1. In this case, I have written something before Question 2 which says that $\partial f^{-1}(A)=f^{-1}(\partial A)$ doesn't hold  in Theorem 4.2. unless $\partial M=\varnothing$.

Comment: @Random It seems that you've found a counterexample to Theorem 4.2 in Hirsch's book, and that the assumptions of his theorem were actually written in a sloppy manner. This particular theorem is stated differently in another version of this book that includes certain corrections.